# Angularjs, ng-view and custom document.ready logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem with angular js.

The thing is, I have bought a html template on the web which has custom javascript that is triggered on `document.ready` (contains a lot of code) and it does something with the GUI to set it all up and running.

As i switch my routes the the initial logic of the `document.ready` that was done for the elements inside the ng-view is lost and GUI looks awful.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When AngularJS changes the view/you switch your route, it will execute the associated controller-function. Therefore, you could call your initialization code from the controller.

Comment: Yes this is feasible, however Angular encourage you to use directives instead of calling it from the controller

Comment: Thanks, i've added the custom logic to a service and injected it and used it in the controller where i need it.